# Preprocessor Directive "Using"

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

From my previous knowledge in learning **C**, I know that preprocessor directive like `#include` , `#define` is ain't a statement that's why as the name implies , it is process before the program is compiled , therefore there's no need for us to append a `;` at the end of it.

In C++, it introduces me a new directive that is `using` , but why this directive append a semicolon? I thought it's just like the previous directive I learn where it's not a statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`using` is not a preprocessor directive. It is seen and analyzed by the compiler proper.

The fact that you often don't put a `;` at the end of `#define` macros is because they are processed as "simple" text replacement by the preprocessor, e.g:

```
#define SOMETHING "abcd";

...
   if (strcmp(thing, SOMETHING) == 0) { ... }
...
```

would be a compiler error since the compiler would see:

```
   if (strcmp(thing, "abcd";) == 0) { ... }
                       //  ^ invalid here
```

Answer (score 0):

`using` can be thought as being a declaration, like e.g. `typedef` is.

And you can ask the compiler to output the result of preprocessing, e.g. with `g++ -C -E` but there is no simple way to ask it to output the effects of `using`